# How to simplify a dictionary of nested lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I currently have this dictionary with nested lists:

```
dict_with_nested_list = {
    'B': [['a', 2], ['b', 4]],
    'A': [['a', 1], ['b', 3]]
}

correct_order = ['A', 'B']
```

I'm trying to simplify it, so that each nested list is in the correct order and its elements are the key and its corresponding values:

```
desired_output = [
    ['a', 1, 2],
    ['b', 3, 4]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ret = OrderedDict()
for order in correct_order:
    for key, value in dict_with_nested_list[order]:
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = []
        ret[key].append(value)

print [[key] + value for key, value in ret.items()]
```

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend keeping some kind of dictionary structure, with a `list` for each value. You can convert it into another structure later, if you want.

```
>>> import collections
>>> dict_with_nested_list = {
...     'B': [['a', 2], ['b', 4]],
...     'A': [['a', 1], ['b', 3]]
... }
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for l in dict_with_nested_list.values():
...     for k,v in l:
...             result[k].append(v)
...
>>> result = {k:sorted(v) for k,v in result.items()}
>>> result
{'b': [3, 4], 'a': [1, 2]}
>>> sorted(result.items())
[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [3, 4])]
>>> [[k]+v for k,v in sorted(result.items())]
[['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn that into a reasonable dictionary like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_output = defaultdict(list)
for key, list_of_pairs in sorted(dict_with_nested_list.items()):
    for lowerkey, value in list_of_pairs:
        dict_output[lowerkey].append(value)

print(dict(dict_output))
```

this results in this dict:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

You can turn that dictionary into your desired output like this:

```
desired_output = [[key] + values for key, values in sorted(dict_output.items())]

print(desired_output)
```

Which results in

```
[['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 4]]
```